# Location(GoogleAPI)(определение места положения)

Tags: android

Хочу получить текущее местоположение, использую `GoogleApiClient`, реализую получение местоположения вот так:

```
location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                                    mGoogleApiClient);
```

В данном случае работа идет через GPS, вопрос, как мне получить местоположение устройства при помощи интернет соединения?

P.S. Через `locationManager` не получается, я всегда получаю `null`

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) = null
```

**UPD**

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**UPD2:**

Сейчас же пытаюсь получить место вот так:

```
location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    l = location.getLongitude();
```

но `location` не идут никакие значения

Comment: Покажите манифест

Comment: Добавил манифест

Comment: А на какой версии тестируете? Если на 6+ то запросили ли в рантайме разрешения на местоположение?

Comment: на 5-й. На 6-й тоже самое, место положение запрашивается

Comment: Точно. @ЮрийСПб, 100% дело в этом!

Comment: Может API ключ....

Comment: Не думаю что дело в ключе. Тогда бы и по gps ничего не работало бы